# Error unzipping with VBS

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704041/creating-batch-script-to-unzip-a-file-without-additional-zip-tools) VBS for unzipping files:

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

outputDirectory = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
zipFile = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)

rem On Error Resume Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If NOT fso.FolderExists(outputDirectory) Then
fso.CreateFolder(outputDirectory)
End If
set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(zipFile).items
objShell.NameSpace(outputDirectory).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
Set fso = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing

rem On Error Goto 0
```

The issue is, when I run it from a .bat with:

`%zip_vbs_path% "%cd%\%zip_temp_dir%\" "%cd%\%OUTPUT_DIR%\!zip_plugin_name_!"`

where:

- `%zip_vbs_path` is the path to said VBS
- `%zip_temp_dir%`=`zip_temp`
- `%OUTPUT_DIR%\!zip_plugin_name_!`=`Output\PluginName.jar`

I get this error:

[image: Error MSG]

When submitting an answer, please [ELIF](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=elif&defid=7754012), because I'm not familiar with the VBS lanugage at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this line:

```
set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(zipFile).items
```

You have `zipFile` set to:

```
Output\PluginName.jar
```

The code you're using should work for `zip` files but`Shell.Application` cannot retrieve the file collection from a `jar` file.