# Extract zip and rar files

Tags: batch-file

The following code (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709923/711006) unzips file named "batchX.zip" kept in folder 'Zipped'

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
Call :UnZipFile "D:\Unzipped\" "D:\Zipped\batchX.zip"
exit /b

:UnZipFile <ExtractTo> <newzipfile>
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs%  echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>%vbs% echo If NOT fso.FolderExists(%1) Then
>>%vbs% echo fso.CreateFolder(%1)
>>%vbs% echo End If
>>%vbs% echo set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>>%vbs% echo set FilesInZip=objShell.NameSpace(%2).items
>>%vbs% echo objShell.NameSpace(%1).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
>>%vbs% echo Set fso = Nothing
>>%vbs% echo Set objShell = Nothing
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
```

However, the file name has to be mentioned in the batch file (batchX.zip) for it to unzip the zip file.

Can we modify this batch code so that we do not need to mention the name, and any zip file placed can be unzipped?

Also, can we unzip a .rar file through a batch code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704041/creating-batch-script-to-unzip-a-file-without-additional-zip-tools

Comment: Thank you, please add the link directly to the question next time. I’ve done it for you this time.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Unzipping any file

> Can we modify this batch code so that we do not need to mention the name, and any zip file placed can be unzipped ?

Batch files can utilize [parameters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), just like other scripting languages. The batch-file syntax is `%1`.

```
Call :UnZipFile "D:\Unzipped\" %1
```

Then call your batch-file with the parameter:

```
myscript.bat zipped-file.zip
```

## Unrarring a file

> Also, can we unzip a .rar file through a batch code?

Yes if you have the appropriate binary. You can download `rar.exe` (a part of [WinRAR](https://www.rarlab.com/)) and use it from a batch-file (see the [manual](http://acritum.com/winrar/console-rar-manual) for details), e.g.

```
rar e %1
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not an expert like you. Can you modify the above code.

Comment: What code? If you want me to apply the solution to the code in your question, please note we don’t do it here. The question would look superfluous if it contained the solution.