# I keep getting an Unsupported image format error in pygame while trying to add a player

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = int(SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.8)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Sidescroller')

x = 200
y = 200
img = pygame.image.load("img.rar").convert_alpha()
rect = img.get_rect()
rect.center = (x, y)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
pygame.quit()
```

I've tried to change the format to other types and to redownload the packages but it doesnt help

Comment: *.rar is not an image file format. Is is some kind of compressed file?

Comment: I'm not sure, i downloaded the file from itch.io but i can't unzip

Comment: [Extract zip and rar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554238/extract-zip-and-rar-files)